# Apply default style of Button to a CustomButton

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

For some reason, I made a CustomButton : Button.

```
<Button x:Name="button1"/>
<my:CustomButton x:Name="button2"/>
```

The problem is that button2 doesn't look like button1,
because the default Button theme isn't applied to CustomButton.

I'm binding button1's style to button2.

```
<Button x:Name="button1"/>
<my:CustomButton x:Name="button2" Style="{Binding Style, ElementName=button1}"/>
```

But it's NOT cool, indeed.

Is there any way to apply the default Button style to a CustomButton?

**Edit 2013/08/10**

CustomButton inherits Button.

My problem is: when I added `button1` and `button2` to a `ToolBar`, the `button2` doesn't look like a `button1`, but like a normal Button.

Thank you for your all help!

Comment: Does CustomButton derives from Button?

Comment: If you don't have defined a default style for your CustomButton, just delete the ´DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeOf(CustomButton), ...´ line in the static constructor in your CustomButton class.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle"  TargetType="BaseTypeOfButtonAndCustomButton">
</Style>
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
</Style>
<Style TargetType="CustomButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
</Style>
```

Where BaseTypeOfButtonAndCustomButton is base class of both Button and CustomButton. It is required in order to set common properties in style. Then you can build new two styles based on ButtonStyle that will be applied by default to Button and CustomButton.

Comment: I know the way to define a default `Style` based on another `Style`, which you taught me. But I would like to a default `Style` which is defined in `ToolBar`. Please read the edited question. Thank you!!!